# Best way to present a small application

Tags: applications, presentation

I'm giving a presentation on a small Timeline Application I made over the past few weeks. How might I make this small application into a much larger speech, about 3 minutes long.

**Should I focus on how it was made or should I just focus on why people should use it?**

Comment: Please describe your audience.  Define your purpose in speaking to this audience on this topic.  Then we might be able to help.

Comment: check this out: http://abstrusegoose.com/380 =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience presenting projects and ideas you should focus on delivering:

1. The problem that your project will solve - **problem**
2. The solution presented by your project - **solution**
3. Who will use it (public) - **who?**
4. Why should people use it (benefits), for instance, will it reduce company costs? - **why?**
5. Who will develop (developed) it and how it will (was) be developed.

If you consider one slide to each topic and 30 secs each slide + your presentation (who are you?), you will get your 3 mins.

Comment: I have a poster and that's about it. i.e. 20" x 30" with info on it. But yeah. I get your point

Comment: You should be succinct. Try to explain it in layman's terms and try presenting it to your girlfriend or mother. If she understands (conveys) the idea. You are one step to go, =)